# How do you make vim scroll offset closer to the top of the page?

Tags: vim

`:set so=999` causes the cursor to stay on the middle line when possible. Is it possible to move the offset even further, like if I want it 3/4 of the way up the page?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`:set so=999` is the extreme; the cursor will stay in the middle of the window as much as possible. So "even further" does not make sense. If you reduce the `'scrolloff'` value, the cursor will be allowed "closer" to the top and bottom. If you aim for an area of ¼ on top and bottom that stays clear of the cursor, you can initialize the value to a fraction of Vim's height:

```
:let &scrolloff = &lines / 4
```

However, this will be a static value that won't be right when you split the window horizontally. As `'scrolloff'` is a global value, you need to adapt it dynamically:

```
:autocmd VimEnter,WinEnter * let &scrolloff = winheight(0) / 4
```

Comment: Ahh thanks for clarifying, I understand what scroll offset means now. In my case then, I'd like to specify an offset only for above the cursor, something like 10 lines above the cursor (with bottom offset unspecified). This means, that my cursor will always try to be near the top of the page.

Comment: There's no such distinction in Vim. You could build an `:autocmd CursorMoved`, checking where you are inside the window with `winline()`, and then adapt the option value like in my answer. But I would not recommend it.